# Why doesn't my TableLayout center my components?

Tags: codenameone

Why doesn't my TableLayout center my components? I'm placing just a few components in a single column, and I want them centered, but the TableLayout's center constraint doesn't seem to work in this case.

I should mention that I tried a BoxLayout, too, and I didn't see any way to center the components in it. Also, I plan to add more components below, so a BorderLayout is out of the question.

Here's how it looks. This matches what I see on my Android phone.

[image]

```
public class Playground {

  private Form current;
  private Resources theme;

  public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

    // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

  }

  public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
      current.show();
      return;
    }

    Form hi = new Form("Table Layout Test");
    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(4, 1);
    hi.setLayout(layout);

    // I specify row and column explicitly or the replaceAndWait() method will put the 
    // replacement below the button instead of above it.
    TableLayout.Constraint center;
    center = layout.createConstraint(0, 0).horizontalAlign(hi.CENTER);
    red = new Label(makeBlankImage(200, 200, 0xFF0000));
    blue = new Label(makeBlankImage(200, 200, 0xFF));
    visibleLabel = red;
    hi.add(center, visibleLabel);

    center = layout.createConstraint(1, 0).horizontalAlign(hi.CENTER);
    Button button = new Button("Switch");
    button.addActionListener(evt -> {
      Label priorImage = visibleLabel;
      //noinspection ObjectEquality
      if (visibleLabel == red) {
        visibleLabel = blue;
      } else {
        visibleLabel = red;
      }
      hi.replaceAndWait(priorImage, visibleLabel, CommonTransitions.createFade(500));
    });
    hi.add(center, button);

    center = layout.createConstraint(2, 0).horizontalAlign(hi.CENTER);
    Label label = new Label("Why aren't any of these");
    hi.add(center, label);

    center = layout.createConstraint(3, 0).horizontalAlign(hi.CENTER);
    SpanLabel label2 = new SpanLabel("components centered?");
    hi.add(center, label2);

    hi.show();
    current = hi;
  }

  private Label red;
  private Label blue;
  private Label visibleLabel;

  private Image makeBlankImage(final int width, final int height, int color) {
    Image image = Image.createImage(width, height);
    Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(color);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    return image;
  }


  public void stop() {
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
layout.setGrowHorizontally(true);
```

The preferred size isn't taking up the entire screen.

Comment: FYI to help Derek get higher points ranking you should check the checkbox next to a correct answer, this also gives you points. It's also nice to upvote and give extra points